# How can I explode a string, edit the data, then implode it with the original delimiters still in place?

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

If I have a string such as this `"Hello | I'm Ben"` and I want to edit the second section, I can use PHP explode like this

```
$newstring = explode("|","Hello | I'm Ben");
```

Once that data has been edited to something new, for example:

```
$newstring[1] = "I'm john";
```

How can I implode the string to once again be `"Hello | I'm John"`?

PHP's implode function returns `Hello I'm John` however it does not put the delimiters back in.

So, is there a way to implode this string and put the `|` between the two exploded sections of the string?

Comment: are you tried `implode("|",$newstring);`

Comment: Read the manual!! A quick glance at http://php.net/function.implode gives your answer: `implode('|', $newstring)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode):

> string implode ( string $glue , array $pieces )

Where:

- `glue` - Defaults to an **empty string.**
- `pieces` - The array of strings to implode.

If you don't specify the `glue` parameter in your `implode()` call, an empty string will be used. In this case, you need to glue the parts with `|`, so you need the following:

```
$newstring = implode('| ', $newstring);
echo $newstring; // => Hello | I'm john
```

However, I don't recommend editing values like this. Perhaps use an array instead?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a glue piece. simply by doing :

```
$foo = implode("|",$newstring);
```

The php implode function can be used with or without this glue piece.
[php implode function](http://fr.php.net/implode)

Answer (score 1):

Edit values using implode or explode isn't a good idea, but you can achieve by this way

```
$newstring = implode('| ', $newstring);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a "glue" argument to `implode()`. (See [the docs](http://php.net/function.implode).)

```
$newstring = explode("|","Hello | I'm Ben");
$newstring[1] = "I'm john";
$newstring = implode("|", $newstring);
```